# TIKZMATH not working with \let\detokenize\relax

Tags: tikzmath

As seen in the picture below, after compiling document.tex...

- ... the first part using mathtikz as usual works fine
- ... the second part using mathtikz via abc.tex (while renewcommanding \test) doesnt work fine

The difference in the second part is, that im getting rid of \detokenize in the abc.tex file by using \let\detokenize\relax.

Note: \detokenize has to stay in the abc.tex file for another reason which is not relevant in this topic

**document.tex:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\newcommand{\mathtikzmark}[2]{\tikz[baseline={(#1.base)},remember picture] \node  (#1) {#2};}
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\link}{ O{shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt} O{} O{above} m m}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, >=stealth, shift={(0,0)}]
        \draw[#1,->,line width=0.4mm] (#4) to node[#3] {#2} (#5) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\test}{}

\begin{document}

% this part works fine
\hspace*{40mm}f(x) = x + \mathtikzmark{B}{3}
\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\mathtikzmark{A}{Attention: blabla}} 
\link[color=black,shorten >=0.5mm,shorten <=1.mm,out=0,in=270, to path={(\tikztostart) -|  (\tikztotarget)}]{A}{B}
%%%


% this part does not 
\renewcommand{\test}{\mathtikzmark{C}{3}}
\hspace*{40mm}f(x) = x + {\begingroup \let\detokenize\relax \input{abc.tex} \endgroup}
\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\mathtikzmark{D}{Attention: blabla}} 
\link[color=black,shorten >=0.5mm,shorten <=1.mm,out=0,in=270, to path={(\tikztostart) -|  (\tikztotarget)}]{D}{C}

    
\end{document}
```

**abc.tex:**

```
{\detokenize {\test}}
```

Compiling document.tex gives us "\tikz\every text node part\tikz" which is not intendet:

[image]

Anyone ideas how to fix it?

Comment: well I wanted to write at your last question that that naturally only works if \detokenize is not needed by other code. Use `\mydetokenize` in your file, and define it accordingly. Then you don't break foreign code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer do i have to define \mydetokenize in document.tex? If yes, do you know a tutorial link how to define it?